# API data not showing on html page | Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

[image]

how to solve this problem? this is my code which does not have any issue but why not showing data in my html page?

```
  // public leadings: Table[];
  leadings: Table[] = [];
  constructor(private TablesService: TablesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLeadings()
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#leadTable').DataTable();
  }

  ngClick() {
    this.getLeadings()
  }

  private getLeadings() {
      // this.TablesService.getLeadings().subscribe(leadings => this.leadings = leadings);
      this.TablesService.getLeadings().subscribe((data: Table[])=>{
        this.leadings = data;
        console.log("Data is here",this.leadings);
      })
  }
```

Comment: please show us your html code as well. do you receive data from your api call in your console.log?

Comment: @Inderseinsein  Don't use jquery and angular together, its not recommended, instead use the angular version of the library you want [angular datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)

Comment: You should share your html. How do you insert leadings in it ?

Comment: @nosTa 

<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let leading of leadings">
 <td class="priceLabel">${{ leading?.amount }}</td>
            <td class="otherLabel">{{ leading?.status }}</td>
            <td class="otherLabel">{{ leading?.date }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

Comment: @user1075296 see my html i submit a answer

Comment: Check the answer you have added a $ in interpolation and that's the issue @Indersein sein

Comment: @Vignesh i add $ in interpolation but same issue

Comment: Please edit your first post and share your whole html code. It says, "No data available in table". Where is it in your HTML? cannot see it